# What to do with 20000 usdt on testnet

Tags: usdt, tether

What can be done with 20000 usdt on testnet?

Can you buy more testnet coins? Can you transfer to your other wallet.

Answer (score 1):

You could swap them to testnet-ETH on the same testnet (not “real” mainnet-ETH, but “fake” testnet-ETH), assuming that [there is](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments) an exchange deployed to the same testnet and assuming that it has enough liquidity for the USDT-ETH pair on that testnet. Simplest is to **change MetaMask to the same testnet**, go to Uniswap, attempt to exchange and see what it offers you.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be done with 20000 usdt on testnet?

Nothing.

Only useful thing they are is for your own internal testing if you are developing an appliaction.